# html: embed streaming video (crossbrowser)

Tags: html, video, embed

i'm trying to embed a .wmv video into my website but doesnt work :(
i've googled and tried `<embed>` and `<video>`

the video i'm using was created by super converter and i've used WMV7 as video codec.

is there a crossbrowser solution for it - or should i better use flash video?

thx in advance

Comment: Yeah, there's this new thing called Youtube, I don't think it'll catch on tho.

Answer (score 1):

The `<video>` tag is specific to [HTML5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5), and is very browser dependent.  If you care about everyone seeing the video you should not be using this tag yet--wait a few years.

As for why the embed is not working, you'll have to show us code to see what is wrong.  Here is an example snippet that *should* work.

```
<OBJECT ID="MediaPlayer" WIDTH="192" HEIGHT="190" CLASSID="CLSID:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95"
STANDBY="Loading Windows Media Player components..." TYPE="application/x-oleobject">
<PARAM NAME="FileName" VALUE="videofilename.wmv">
<PARAM name="autostart" VALUE="false">
<PARAM name="ShowControls" VALUE="true">
<param name="ShowStatusBar" value="false">
<PARAM name="ShowDisplay" VALUE="false">
<EMBED TYPE="application/x-mplayer2" SRC="videofilename.wmv" NAME="MediaPlayer"
WIDTH="192" HEIGHT="190" ShowControls="1" ShowStatusBar="0" ShowDisplay="0" autostart="0"> </EMBED>
</OBJECT>
```

With any HTML questions, you should tell us what browser and OS you are using.  Again, source code is very important to diagnosing problems.